# PHPStorm - "Cannot accept external xdebug connection" on vagrant

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying - unsuccessfully - to use the combo PHPstorm/xdebug/vagrant. Every time I try to debug something, PHPStorm throws me an `Cannot accept external xdebug connection` error.

Here's the xdebug configuration:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so"
extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_connect_back = on
html_errors=1
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.idekey = "vagrant"
xdebug.default_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.33.10
```

The images below shows my phpstorm config:
[image: Remote debug settings]
[image: HTTP Request settings]
[image: Web Application settings]
[image: Remote server settings]

Also, my output from `php -i | grep xdebug`:

```
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
xdebug
xdebug support => enabled
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => vagrant => vagrant
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => On => On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => 192.168.33.10 => 192.168.33.10
xdebug.remote_log => /var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log =>                 /var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

My host machine is running Elementary OS and my vagrant box is running Scotch box (so, both are ubuntu 14.04).

The main question is: how to setup the PHP to debug my PHP codes with xdebug on my current enviroment?

Comment: 1) Remove `extension=xdebug.so` line -- it's not needed; 2) Since you will be debugging web app (am I right?) .. then please capture `phpinfo()` output via browser (provide xdebug section). This is mainly because you may have different php.ini files for CLI (terminal) and actual Apache; 3) Your screenshots showing that you are editing **Default** configs -- not actual configs. You need to click on "+" button to actually create one which you can then use later 4) Provide xdebug log 5) Screenshot of xdebug settings in PhpStorm (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug)

Comment: Also: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Answer (score 2):

Just removed the `extension=xdebug.so` line from xdebug.ini and it worked like a charm.

Thanks @LazyOne, your answer saved my day :)